# Cannot get in Lens Kubernetes details pane of pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I've installed Lens on my Mac and have it setup to connect to the cluster from EKS. However when I select Workloads - Pods. I can see the pods but when I click on each pod I'm not able to open the details pane of the pod. What am I missing?
I've kubectl version v1.22.0 installed.